# Spring boot throwing java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, cxf

I am doing a test spring boot project implementing REST services.
The REST service adds, deletes, updates and get patient details from in-memory map.

While I am able to get, add and delete patients using generic URL like http://localhost:8443/restws/patientservice/patients (GET)

Following path parameter URL is not working
http://localhost:8443/restws/patientservice/patients/{123}

Below is pom.xml, interface and service code that I have implemented

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ranjan.jaxrs.service</groupId>
<artifactId>PatientService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>PatientService</name>
<description>Rest Services for patients</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

PatientService interface

```
package com.ranjan.jaxrs.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Produces("application/xml,application/json")
@Path("/patientservice")
public interface PatientService {
@Path("/patients")
@GET
public List<Patient> getPatientsList();

@Path("/patients/{patientId}")
@GET
public Patient getPatientById(@PathParam("patientId") long id);

@Path("/patients")
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml,application/json")
public Response createPatient(Patient patient);

@Path("/patients")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/xml,application/json")
public Response updatePatient(Patient patient);

@Path("/patients/{patientId}")
@DELETE
public Response deletePatient(@PathParam(value="patientId") long id);

@Path("/patients")
@DELETE
public Response deletePatient();
```

}

PatientServiceImpl

```
 package com.ranjan.jaxrs.service;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;

  import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
  import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
  import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

  @Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {

Map<Long,Patient> patientRepository=new HashMap<Long,Patient>();

public  PatientServiceImpl() {

    System.out.println("Inside PAtient service.....");
    init();

}

public void init() {
    Patient patient=new Patient();
    patient.setId(123L);
    patient.setName("Ranjan");

    patientRepository.put(patient.getId(), patient);

}

@Override
public List<Patient> getPatientsList() {
    Collection<Patient> patientCollection=patientRepository.values();
    List<Patient> responseList=new ArrayList<Patient>(patientCollection);
    return responseList;
}

@Override
public Patient getPatientById(long id) {
     Patient patient=patientRepository.get(id);
     if(patient==null) {
         //throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
         throw new NotFoundException();
     }
     return patient;
}

@Override
public Response createPatient(Patient patient) {
    patientRepository.put(patient.getId(), patient);
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@Override
public Response updatePatient(Patient patient) {

    Response response;

    if (patient!=null) {
    patientRepository.put(patient.getId(), patient);
    response=Response.ok().build();
    }else {
        //response=Response.notModified().build();
        throw new PatientBusinessException();
    }

    return response;
}

@Override
public Response deletePatient(long id) {
    patientRepository.remove(id);
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@Override
public Response deletePatient() {
    patientRepository.clear();
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

}

Stacktrace exception received

```
20-05-18 09:27:18.629  WARN 24876 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper  : javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toInternalServerErrorException(SpecExceptions.java:79)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(ExceptionUtils.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:227)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
  at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
  at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1348)
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1299)
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:825)
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:789)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you're trying to call the init() method in the constructor, but the repository hasn't had the chance to be injected yet.

Try removing the method call from the constructor and adding the @PostContruct annotation to it.

Comment: same error post removing init() call from constructor and adding @PostConstruct annotation to init().

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured due to wrong import for @PathParam this was imported from
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam; and should have been from import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;